# Finding hourly passenger loads given boarding and deboarding time

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table of transport records for a bus company:

```
CREATE TABLE ride_txn(
passenger_no int(11) pk,
txn_time timestamp,
action varchar(10)
)
```

where the action could be "Board" or "Deboard".

Say I have 2 rows where for passenger_no. 100, he boarded at 1.30pm and alighted at 4.30pm.

```
passenger_no    txn_time    action
100             13:30:00    Board
100             16:30:00    Deboard
```

Can I write an sql query to retrieve the hours that he is in the bus? I do the count at the beginning of each hour so he was in the bus at 2pm, 3pm and 4pm. In other words, I am trying to get something like

```
passenger_no    hour_in_bus
100             2
100             3
100             4
```

Comment: i'm using mysql, please.

Comment: In that example, you really want those 3 rows? I don't understand the logic. Don't you want the result to be `passenger_no: 100` `hour_in_bus: 3`?

Comment: he boarded at 1.30pm and alighted at 4.30pm. hence, he was in the bus at 2pm, 3pm and 4pm. I am intending to do this for many passengers to find out how many passengers are in the bus at 2pm, 3pm, 4pm etc.

Comment: I see, it's an interesting exercise. BTW, the question title seems to have little to do with what you are asking! You may probably want to rephrase it.

Comment: We would probably use a word more like "deboarded" rather than "alighted". That word is not a common one or a familiar one to most English speakers. :)

Comment: haha please feel free to change the wording as it has little impact to the solution ;)

Comment: I only mention it for your information and the realistic concern that it will confuse many people about what you're doing.

Comment: Can a passenger board and deboard the train several times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a start:

```
select
    passenger_no, hr
from
    ride_txn rt,
    (
        select  0 hr union all select  1 union all select  2 union all
        select  3    union all select  4 union all select  5 union all
        select  6    union all select  7 union all select  8 union all 
        select  9    union all select 10 union all select 11 union all
        select 12    union all select 13 union all select 14 union all
        select 15    union all select 16 union all select 17 union all
        select 18    union all select 19 union all select 20 union all
        select 21    union all select 22 union all select 23
    ) hrs
where
    action = 'Board' and
    hrs.hr between
        hour(txn_time) /* could add 3599 seconds to only count top of the hour */
        and
        (
            select min(txt_time) from ride_txn rt2
            where 
                    rt2.passenger_no = rt.passenger_no
                and rt2.txt_time > rt.txt_time and action = 'Deboard'
        )
```

I had to assume that the events will pair off correctly and also that the "deboard" time will be greater than the "board" time. So nothing spans midnight and it takes place within a single day. It would handle multiple pairs within the day though.

I'm not sure if `hour()` is actually a MySQL function but I'm sure you can find the equivalent one. I'm also assuming it returns a number from 0 to 23.

Comment: That returns the passenger was on board at 13:00.

Comment: @Andrew, that's why I added the note about adding 3599 seconds. We didn't get details about how the times are stored (or even the datatype of that column.)

Comment: That doesn't help, because if the board time was actually 13:00, you would be missing that hour. You really need the complete time, not just the hour.

Comment: If the board time was exactly 13:00 then adding 3599 seconds gets you to 13:59:59 which is still in the hour that began at 1pm. I really don't know exactly what OP wants but it's quite easy to compensate.

Answer (score 0):

```
select id,y.tm from
( 
 select id,
   max(case when action = 'Deboard' then hour(dt) end) as d_time,
   max(case when action = 'Board' then hour(dt) end) as b_time
 from tablename 
 group by id) x
join
(
 select distinct hour(dt) as tm from tablename
) y
on y.tm between x.b_time and x.d_time
```

This would work assuming you have all the 24 hours in the table.

Comment: That doesn't work. Why are you discarding the minutes? If the passenger boards 13:30, he wasn't on board at 13:00.

Answer (score 0):

```
with cte as (select a.passenger_no,case when minute(a.txn_time) > 0 or Second(a.txn_time) > 0  then hour(a.txn_time) + 1 else hour(a.txn_time) end as brd_time,
             hour(b.txn_time) debrd_time,
             from ride_txn a inner join ride_txn b
            on a.passenger_no = b.passenger_no where a.action = 'Board' and b.action = 'DeBoard')

select
    passenger_no, hr_12
from
    cte,
    (
        select  0 hr, 0 hr_12  union all select  1,1 union all select  2,2 union all
        select  3,3    union all select  4,4 union all select  5,5 union all
        select  6,6    union all select  7,7 union all select  8,8 union all 
        select  9,9    union all select 10,10 union all select 11,11 union all
        select 12,12    union all select 13,1 union all select 14,2 union all
        select 15,3    union all select 16,4 union all select 17,5 union all
        select 18,6    union all select 19,7 union all select 20,8 union all
        select 21,9    union all select 22,10 union all select 23,11
    ) hrs
where
    hrs.hr between brd_time and debrd_time
```